# Big query decorator applicable for views?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is big query table decorator applicable for views?

If so, how it is interpreted for multiple tables in a view?

Comment: Bigquery table decorators are part of the SQL-oid syntax of your queries -- instead of just naming the table you can append to the table name e.g `@<start>-` to mean "only look at records added since `start`, a time in milliseconds since the epoch, until `right now`".  Can you please clarify with an example what "multiple tables in a view" you have in mind here...?  Thanks!

Comment: Already using decotars for tables and now we need to build a view in big query and that view will join several tables. The question is how that view and underlying tables will be queried if we use views with decorators

Answer (score 1):

Using a decorator with a view won't have any meaning, since views don't have snapshot versions the way tables do. You *can* create a view that uses relative time table decorators, and those should be fine (they'll be evaluated at the time of the query).

Comment: All I wanted to achieve is to apply decorator values to the tables referenced by a view. Looks like it is not doable. Thank you though.

Comment: Filed a feature request; https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=202&thanks=202&ts=1419875021